# Info or help on creating SwiftUI array that uses a model for data and user input for number of items in array?

Tags: arrays, swiftui, arraylist, dynamic-list

I need to create a view with a list.  The number of items in the list is called here "Number of Stands"

[image]

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Stand: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String {
        return self.stand
    }
    var stand: String
    let area: String
    let speed: Int
    var rf: Int
}


extension Stand {
    static let Mock_Stand = Stand(stand: "32", area: "2.4", speed: 0, rf: 0)
}
```

After hitting "lets go" i go to this screen.

[image]

Here is the code for my list row.

```
import SwiftUI

struct StandRowView: View {
    let stand: String
    @Binding var speedCurrent: String
    let rfactor: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            HStack{
                Text("Stand")
                Text(stand)
                TextField("Enter Speed", text: $speedCurrent)
                    .frame(width: 110, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .background()
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 5)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.trailing, 30)
                Text(rfactor)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for this screen currently.

```
struct Speeds1View: View {

let title: String
let productArea: String
let noStands: String
let billetArea: String
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@State var txtspeedCurrent: String
@State private var rF = ""
@State private var standNo: Int = 0
@State private var rFCalculated: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack{
            ZStack{
                List{
                    HStack(alignment: .center){
                        Spacer()
                    VStack(){
                            Text("# of Stands")
                            Text(self.noStands)
                            Text("Billet Area")
                            Text(self.billetArea)
                            Text("Product Area")
                            Text(self.productArea)
                            Text(" Reduction Ratio: \(RedRatio) : 1")
                            Text("Testing")
                            Text(" Ave. Area Red: \(AveAreaRed)%")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }

                    ForEach(0..<standCount, id: \.self) { standCount in
                        StandRowView(stand:"\(standCount + 1)", speedCurrent: $txtspeedCurrent, rfactor: "Area1/Area2")
                    }

                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
            }

        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.backward")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                })
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    //                    updateText()
                    //                    dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 25)
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.blue, Color.gray)
                })
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationTitle("Calculate Area, \(title)")
}
}
```

With this code my stands are not separated by ID.  i get this when i begin to type in something for "Speed".

[image]

so.. i need to separate each row by stand no.  then i need to be able to do a .onchange so that i can create a formula to calculate Stand 1 area / Stand 2 area and update the text on right but that will be easy i think.

any help showing me a similar project online i can reference would be a huge help.

Comment: Where's the code for the `StandRowView`? You probably need to pass the `standCount` (from the `ForEach`) in as a unique ID of some sort.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your problem is mainly caused by not having a proper data source or rather not having one at all. You do have a struct but you aren’t using it. You should create an array of your struct and use that in your ForEach instead of looping over an index

Comment: create an array of my struct then use in my for each. ill look that up.  thanks

Comment: well, my problem is i dont know how many are in my array until someone types in a stand count.  how do i say make "5" stand rows in my list using this struct "Stand"?  and make the ID the number of stand iterated.  any example i find online has nothing related to this.  hoping someone here may have seen an example like this

Comment: 5 is an input to the view right? Build the array in .onAppear() of the view in a loop using noStands. And make noStands an Int directly so you can do `for i in 1...noStands {...}`

Comment: 5 is an example for noStands.   I will need to change this. (As u know I’m sure.  I’m not good at this). Anyhoo.   So I can make an array w .onApear()?  Ok. So I do for i in i and make array noStands’s Int.  Let’s say that’s 5.  How can I then assign struct Stand to that?  I’ll do some googling on .onappear arrays.  Thank u for any help. 